# Videoview in a viewflipper still playing when i leave the view to the previous child

Tags: android, viewflipper, android-videoview

I have a viewflipper controller with different views.

I click in the firsview and i go to secoundview with and animation.

The secondview is a video view with a streaming video inside (it works perfectly)

the problem is when i go back using the back physical `button(flipper.showPrevious())` 
I override that for stop the video before leave with `videoView.stopPlayback();`

When i come back to the firstview i still have the video playing over the firstview (only the video, or a black screen if i did the `stopPlayback()` before)

How can i solve that? What i am doing wrong?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could always try `videoView.setVisibility(int);` [function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29).